# I need a script to create a folder and sub folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need a script that will create a main folder with a name like request #...... and the number has to be entered by the user, and sub folders that will always have the same name.
thank you.

Comment: `mkdir "request #\same name"`

Comment: @Stephan. I think you forgot a part of the question. there's a number that need to be enntered by the user. Maybe with a popup who will ask "which request number?" and insert it into the folder's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you are looking for the below code.

**set /p**- prompts the value from user.

**md**- to create a folder

```
@echo off
set /p number="Enter number: "

::main folder
md request#%number%

::sub folders
md request#%number%\request#%number%_SubFolder1
md request#%number%\request#%number%_SubFolder2
md request#%number%\request#%number%_SubFolder3
md request#%number%\request#%number%_SubFolder4
```

you can create n number of sub folder using for loop. The below code will create parent directory and n number of sub folders based on the value you enter.

```
@echo off
set /p number="Enter number: "
::main folder
md request#%number%
::sub folder
for /L %%a in (1,1,%number%) do md request#%number%\request#%number%_SubFolder%%a
```

if you input the value 4 then below folder structure will be created.

```
-request#4
 -request#4_SubFolder1
 -request#4_SubFolder2
 -request#4_SubFolder3
 -request#4_SubFolder4
```

**EDIT:**
Below code will trigger the GUI inputbox, to get the user input. VBS script will be invoked indirectly to display the input box. Sub folder 'iAmSubFolder' will be created under the parent folder. Change this name, if you want a different one.

```
@echo off
::input box
echo wscript.echo inputbox("Please enter the number","This is title bar") >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs"') do set number=%%a

::Just to make clear, assigning folder names to variables
set parentFolder= request#%number%
set subFolder= %parentFolder%\iAmSubFolder
::to remove any existing folder
::creating parent folder, if not exists
if not exist %parentFolder% md %parentFolder%
::create SubFolderWithSameName, if not exists
if not exist %subFolder% md %subFolder%
```

Final script with vbs extension:

```
dim filesys, newfolder, newfolderpath, number
number=inputbox("Please enter the number","This is title bar")
'update the folder path in the below line
newfolderpath="C:\Users\310294\Desktop\test\"
newfolderpath = newfolderpath + "request#" +number
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not filesys.FolderExists(newfolderpath) Then
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath)
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath+ "\Photos")
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath+ "\Videos")
msgbox "Folders are created!"
End If
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. It works for the first part (main folder). regarding the subfolder, they will always have the same name and no number, but ofcours have to be created under the same main folder.
Also, the question to enter a number comes in a cmd window.
Any other way to get a windows popup?
Thank you

Comment: check this out.

`code` @echo off
::input box
echo wscript.echo inputbox("Please enter the number","Request Folder") >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs"') do set number=%%a

::Just to make clear, assigning folder names to variables
set parentFolder= request#%number%
set subFolder= %parentFolder%\iAmSubFolder
::to remove any existing folder
::creating parent folder, if not exists
if not exist %parentFolder% md %parentFolder%
::SubFolderWithSameName, if not exists
if not exist %subFolder% md %subFolder%
pause
`code`

Comment: The code is very confusing because it's in one block.Anyway, I tried to put it in a .bat file an run it, but besides a box that comes and disappear right away, nothing happened.

Comment: I cant format it properly. Sorry about that. Added the updated code in the original response. Check the EDIT section

Comment: it's easier to read like this. I'm sorry but when I meant subfolders with same name, I meant that I will create it like in this example:
Main folder: Request# 1233
Subfolders: Pictures, PO's, Invoices, Reports.

The subfolders will never change.

Comment: Replace the last line of the code(if not exist %subFolder% md %subFolder%) with below line.

`code` md %parentFolder%\picture %parentFolder%\photo %parentFolder%\pic `code`

Similar way, you can add as many folders as you want by adding the subfolder names in the format %parentFolder%\yourfoldername (each folder names should be separated by space).

Comment: that seems great for now. Just one last question. when I get the input box, we can see behind it the cmd box. is it possible to minimize it so users only sees the input box?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215401/discussion-between-kalicharan-n-and-alain).